# Get specific information from multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let say I have a array in this format:

```
arr = [{
         "id":"11",
         "children":[
                      { "id":"9"},
                      { "id":"5", "children":[ {"id":"4"} ] }
                    ]
       },
       {
         "id":"10",
         "children":[{ "id":"7"} ]
       }
      ]
```

And now I would like to **get all ID's that are apparent** in this array:

```
11,9,5,4,10,7
```

For that I would use a recursive code similar to this one:

```
ids = []

def find_ids arr
 arr.each do |entry|
   ids << entry["id"] if entry["id"]
   find_ids(entry["children"]) if entry["children"]
 end 
end
```

**What would you do to get the ids?**

**Do you maybe know a really short version?**

Thanks

Comment: John, I trust the edit I did is OK with you. I reformatted the input array to bring out its structure and to also avoid the need for readers to scroll horizontally to see it.  I also attached a variable to it (`arr`) so readers can reference the variable without have to define it. It would be helpful (whenever giving an example) to show your desired result as a Ruby object. Here you might ask for `[11, 9, 5, 4, 10, 7]`.

Comment: Make that `["11", "9", "5", "4", "10", "7"]`, unless you want the strings converted to integers.

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully before posting my answer, which is nearly the same as what you propose except I allowed for key-value pairs where the key is not `:id` and the value is not an array. Note `{ "id": 1 } #=> {:id=>1}`, that is, the quotes are redundant (and are only needed when the string contains a space (`{"a b": 1 } #=> {:"a b"=>1}`).  As a result, `{ "id": 1 }["id"] #=> nil`. You need `{ id: 1 }[:id] #=> 1`.

Comment: You do need recursion to obtain the desired array when `arr` has alternating nested arrays and hashes (to any level). If the structure of `arr` is fixed as in the example, with only non-array values allowed to vary, then, yes, there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you wanna to use shorter version:

```
def get_ids(arr)
  p =->(hsh) { Array === hsh["children"] ? ([hsh["id"]] + hsh["children"].map(&p)) : hsh["id"] }

  arr.map(&p).flatten
end

get_ids(arr)
# => ["11", "9", "5", "4", "10", "7"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def grab_ids(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |h,a|
    h.each do |k,v|
      case v
      when Array
        a.concat(grab_ids(v))
      else
        a << v if k == :id
      end
    end
  end
end

grab_ids arr
  #=> ["11", "9", "5", "4", "10", "7"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way is to use lambda:

```
def get_ids(arr)
  p = ->(a, exp) do
    a.each do |hsh|
      exp << hsh["id"]
      p.(hsh["children"], exp) if Array === hsh["children"]
    end
    exp
  end
  p.(arr, [])
end

get_ids(arr)
# => ["11", "9", "5", "4", "10", "7"]
```